# How to place Image inside Grid in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Forms project and I'm trying to create this page in xaml:
[image]

I am trying to create it with this xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="A" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="B" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="C" />
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="D" />
        <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="E" />
        <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="F" />

        <Label Text="A2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
        <Label Text="B2" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>

    <Label Text="Details" />
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="All" />
        <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Scheduled" />
        <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Unscheduled" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

But then it looks like this:

[image]

Problem is there is spacing before "Details" label. When I remove image it looks good:
[image]

How can I place image inside Grid so that it looks like first image?

Comment: Besides any problem here, I would try to lose the overall StackLayout and just put all of the layout in a Grid. Your problem will then probably be resolved as well, and draw time should improve as well.

Comment: My page is actually much more complicated then this. There are couple of elements that are not shown. For example, bellow Details label there are ListView elements. And Grid should be inside ListView header so that is scrolls together with ListView elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should put background color on your elements so you can better visualize their real dimensions. After that control your Vertical options.

Furthermore I suggest you to put everything inside a bigger grid where you can define your actual grid and your label.